# Blender rendered image is blocky

Tags: rendering

The viewport shading looks different compared to the actual render.

[image]
[image]

What could cause this?

If anyone wants to check out the file it can be downloaded here: https://mega.nz/file/gs0SmThD#2lBTSQsVocjnbZ2IN7_1Ih8HDpWeeNSw2j8LhY0z05E

Comment: Please don't use an external site for uploads and upload any file in native .blend format rather than compressed. https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: I think everything got duplicated by accident. There are 4 lamps, 2 floors, 8 fence posts, 10 window frames, etc. I highly recommend giving the objects proper names then you see easily in the outliner that there are 4 lamps & not only 2 ;-) If you want to add lights I recommend scaling down the scene to real-world size. At the moment the lamps are 16m tall and require a 20000W light to shed some light. Also, 16000(!) samples + no threshold is crazy. This takes hours to render. Such a low-poly scene will already look nice with only 20(!) samples+denoiser =>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jjc5.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is called z-fighting (you can search here for that) and it happens, if you have two objects on the same place with the same form and size, Blender does not "know" which is in front. So you should delete your double objects. You can "check" for double objects by just selecting them and move them to see whether there is still another.

Watch here:

[image]

if i render after moving away the double object, it looks fine:

[image]

but still the lower object is double too...